# laravel DB order by if null?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So i'm trying to order some stuff. Like that:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $match = Match::get(); 
        $map = $request->get('map');
        $match = DB::table('matches')
        ->paginate(15);
        $this->title("MIX žaidimai");
        
        if ($map) {
        $match = DB::table('matches')
        ->where('map', $map)
        ->paginate(15);
        $this->title("MIX žaidimai");
        }
        if ($request->routeIs('matches.live')) {
        $match = DB::table('matches')
        ->where('state', '0')
        ->where('map', $map)
        ->paginate(15);
        $this->title("LIVE MIX žaidimai");
        }
        
        $this->pageView('matches::index', compact('match'));
    }
```

So if i choose on my site link like: /matches/live?map=de_dust2 map ordering works fine, but if i choose /matches/live i dont get it nothing. Any help? I know this code not good at all, but i'm learing laravel so dont be mad on me :) thanks! Sorry if i dont know how to explain better my situation and thanks for helping me! :)

**UPDATED:**
Thanks for answers. But i need if route is not ?map i need to see all maps. Example: /matches/live returning 0 items, becouse map is not selected. I need /matches/finished show all matches with state 0 and if choose the map in /matches/finished?map=$map show matches with state 0 and choosed map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your query like this

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($map) {

            $title = "MIX žaidimai";
        }
        if ($request->routeIs('matches.live')) {
            $title = "LIVE MIX žaidimai";
        }
        $this->title($title);

        $map = $request->get('map');
        $matchQuery = Match::query();

        if ($map) {
            $matchQuery->where('map', $map);
        }

        if ($request->routeIs('matches.live')) {
            $matchQuery->where('state', '0');
           
        }

        $matchQuery->paginate(15);

        $match = $matchQuery;
        $this->pageView('matches::index', compact('match'));
    }
```

or

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
      if ($map) {

            $title = "MIX žaidimai";
        }
        if ($request->routeIs('matches.live')) {
            $title = "LIVE MIX žaidimai";
        }
        $this->title($title);
       $map = $request->get('map');
      $match= Match::query()->when(!empty( $map),function($query)use($map){
                    $query->where('map', $map);
                })->when($request->routeIs('matches.live'),function($query)use($map){
                    $query->where('state', '0');
                   
                })->paginate(15);
    
    $this->pageView('matches::index', compact('match'));
}
```

if your query still not returning then let me know in comment .

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i need if route is not ?map i need to see all maps. Example: /matches/live returning 0 items, becouse map is not selected. I need /matches/finished show all matches with state 0 and if choose the map in /matches/finished?map=$map show matches with state 0 and choosed map.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $map = $request->get('map');
    $match = DB::table('matches')->query();
    if ($map) {
        $match = $match->where('map', $map);
        $title = "MIX žaidimai";
    }

    if ($request->routeIs('matches.live')) {
        $match = $match->where('map', $map)->where('state', '0');
        $title = "LIVE MIX žaidimai";
    }
    $match = $match->paginate(15);
    $this->title($title);
    $this->pageView('matches::index', compact('match'));
}
```

Comment: ERROR: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::query()